# React Bootstrap Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the navigation bar component offered by react-bootstrap. But I am getting a weird error. Below is the screenshot of the stacktrace.
[image]

This is my code for navigation bar.

```js
import React from "react";
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem} from "react-bootstrap";
import navigationbarlogo from "../assets/images/navigationbarlogo.png"
import navstyle from "../assets/css/NavigationBar.css"

class NavigationBar extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
                <Navbar bsStyle="inverse">
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand style={navstyle}>
                            <img src={navigationbarlogo} alt={'logo for navigation bar'}/>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000">Tweelyze</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Analytics</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">About Us</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
        );
    }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here

Comment: Double check that you are successfully importing your `react-bootstrap` components, and that they are not `undefined` on import.

Answer (score 0):

check your imported component. we use import  `{component-name} from ''` to import named export and `import 'any-component-name' from ''` to import default import.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way your importing your styles, this error usually occurs when the module you imported does is not found. Can I see the directory of your file so that we can check if it loads there correctly?

Comment: No The directory of your file... Maaybe it's the NavStyle or navigation bar logo there might be no exported thing there.